# Google SignIn does not work with Play Games Services enables, but works without

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, google-signin, google-play-games

First of all let's have a look at the code that works perfectly fine. This is how we setup our Google Api Client:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail() 
                .requestIdToken(AppActivity.this.getResources().getString(R.string.server_client_id))
                .build();

GoogleSignIn.googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
```

Then this for connecting:

```
// GPGS needs optional apparently, at least it crashes without. 
// Normal (non GPGS) SignIn works either way
googleApiClient.connect(SIGN_IN_MODE_OPTIONAL);
```

Then we call login. The overlay appears, I select my email, login runs through and all is fine:

```
public static void loginGoogleSDK()
{
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(googleApiClient);
    GameApplication.getActivity().startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}
```

---

Now there's the Google Play Games Services login which is quite similar, but does always return a **User Cancelled** error. The GPGS overlay appears, one can select an email, then it disappears and the error is given back:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .requestIdToken(AppActivity.this.getResources().getString(R.string.server_client_id))
            .build();

GoogleSignIn.googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Games.API)
            .addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
```

Connect and login are completely equal.

The **User Cancelled** result code, comes back here:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // cancelled = true when using GPGS 
    GameLog.i("On Activity Result called, cancelled? " + (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) );


    // [Other code for handling login....]


}
```

Does anybody know what's causing this and how we can get login with Google Player Games Services working?

Answer (score 1):

My code was 100% correct.

I had to add my email under "Testers" in the Google Play Developer Console under my Game.

This is not necessary for Google+ SignIn, but it is for games.

Answer (score 0):

Im having a similar problem, but from what i have read, you can't use Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API with Games.API.

Comment: Check this guide here, it's possible: https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/offline-access